# Python exception if error occurs to use different URL - openrouteservice

Tags: python, exception, openrouteservice

So I wrote a script to request routes from the ORS-API but with a local hostes instance of ORS - problem is I can not host all of Europe, but there are coordinates not within my locally hosted area. Is there a way to have an exception, if the out-of-reach error occurs to use the global instance of ORS instead of my locally hosted one?

The script I wrote uses following code to pull requests:

```
body = {"coordinates":coords,"extra_info":["waycategory"]}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Type': 'application/geo+json; charset=utf-8'
}
call = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/ors/v2/directions/driving-hgv/geojson', json=body, headers=headers)

weiter = call.text

data = json.loads(weiter)
```

Now I want to have an exception like, to use:

```
call = requests.post('http://openrouteservice.org/ors/v2/directions/driving-hgv/geojson', json=body, headers=headers)

#if out of reach-error (coordinates not in the local hosted instance)
```

Is there some way to do that? any hint is appreciated!!